# Maximo Processing Rule

Tags: conditional-statements, maximo, outbound

In Maximo 7.5, I need to add a processing rule to a publish channel that will skip records where the laborcode starts with 99.  However, simply using a LIKE evaluation type with a value of 99 will skip laborcodes with 99 anywhere in the attribute.  Does anyone know a way to create a processing rule that only skips if the first two characters are 99?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar requirement before. What I did was:

1. Create a relationship in the Database Configuration for the object.
2. Create a whereclause that substrings the field value, in your case, the laborcode. The substring should return the first two characters, in your case, '99'.
3. Instead of using the LIKE evaluation type, use EQUALS and use the relationship you created and link it to the field where the substring value should be.

This way, it only checks the first two characters. It doesn't read the entire field value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using 99%?

Default Maximo wildcard searching for `searchterm` results in Maximo putting wildcards before and after the search term, `like '%searchterm%'`, unless your `searchterm` includes wildcards, in which case it will just use your wildards.